# AWS ECS Fargate - specify file path in host volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create cluster in ECS Fargate with a Docker-hub image. To spin the container I have to upload a file config.json in the host so that the path could be mounted as -v /configfile/path:/etc/selenium

In local we can specify the path of json file like below.

docker run -d --name selenium -p 4444:4444 -v /E/config.json:/etc/selenium/

Whereas I am not sure where to upload the config.json file in ECS Faragte and use that path in volume.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do anything related to the host when using Fargate. The whole point of Fargate is that it is a "serverless" container runtime, so you have no access to the underlying server at all.

You need to look into other ways of achieving your requirement in Fargate. For example you could first copy the file to S3, and then configure the entrypoint script in your docker container to download the file from S3 before starting selenium.